# I asked the user to enter his (int)ID and then I want to take the ID and store it in an array to continue

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Now when I call the method in the "switch" , I'm confused about how can I put the ID that the user entered as a parameter of the "equation" method 
I've done this code but still have no idea what to do to make it work

Here is the switch:

```
switch(numberChosen)
    {
        case "1":
            Scanner readID = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your ID: ");
            String ID = readID.nextLine();
            int yourID = Integer.parseInt(ID);

            equation();
    }
```

And here is the method:

```
public static double equation(int[] ID_)
{
    ID_ = new int [];
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        x += ID_[i];
        return x;
    }
    for(int j = ID_.length; j > ID_.length-2; j--){
        y += ID_[j];
        return y;
    }
    double eq = x * ( 3*y-2 ) + 1;
    return eq;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't build.

Comment: @takendarkk, now when the case is "1" the program will continue in case "1" code 
and there is my problem when I need to send the ID that the user entered before as a parameter of the **equation** method .. because the ID is not an array but the parameter expected by **equation** is an array

Comment: @nicomp, I know for now, but I need to put an integer as a parameter when the parameter expected by the method is an array!

Comment: Voted to close because the example code doesn't build and no effort is being made to fix it.

Comment: What does equation() want to do with an array, and why do you want to sent it a userId? Is this a class assignment? Maybe you could give us more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

in the method parameter, you can make an int input. for example:

```
public static double equation(int[] ID_, int userID)
```

This will allow you to put the int that the user inserted in the switch case statement into that method.

Then you can use the variable:

```
userID
```

to do whatever you must with it inside of the equation method. Here is an example of that right here:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   //Original int
   int originalInt = 1;

   //Method that takes an int as an argument and does something with it
   doSomethingWithInt(originalInt);

}

//Your method
public static int doSomethingWithInt(int someInt){
      someInt = someInt + 5;

      return someInt;
}.
```

Hope this helps.